# Charles Proxy Rewrite & MapLocal - how to match exact query

Tags: charles-proxy

I only want to return certain response specifically for `/path/embed=profile&prefetch=true&couples_only=false` and NOT `embed=profile&prefetch=true&couples_only=false&ANYTHINGELSE`

But Charles seems to be treating the 2 queries the same
[image]

What I've tried

1. `/path/embed=profile&prefetch=true&couples_only=false?` - hoping the `?` will match 1 character or nothing, ruling out the wanted longer queries
   [image]
2. `embed=profile&prefetch=true&couples_only=false(?!&)` - standard regex, tested in regexr.com

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember, it's a bug and it hasn't fixed ever since.

You might try [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io), which is similar to Charles and it will solve your problem.

Here is the step:

1. Setup the [certificate](https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/macos) on your macOS (Certificate -> Install on macOS)
2. Make a request
3. Right-click to show a menu context -> Tool -> [Map Local](https://docs.proxyman.io/advanced-features/map-local) or [Breakpoint](https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/script)

[image]

4. Create a rule with default value -> **It will match exactly the query** as you wish.

- For the Map Local, you can modify the local file in the Editor.
- For the Scripting (It's the same with ReWrite, but write by Javascript)

[image: Map Local]

- Disclaimer: I create this app. Hope that it can help you for daily works.